# Difference in passing the object inside aes() in ggplot and passing the same object outside ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the difference in mapping the Species to color aesthetic inside ggplot and inside geom_point. I am using iris data set.

```
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species), data = 
trainData)+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth()

AND

ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length), data = trainData)+
geom_point(aes(color = Species))+
geom_smooth()
```

The graph I am getting:

Output for the first code
[image]

Output for the second code
[image]

Comment: The geoms inherit all aesthetic mappings which were set in `ggplot`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks got it!

Comment: But why I got -2? I am a beginner in data science and at stack overflow is asking such question  wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the aes() call in the second case colours the points but this is not carried forward to the colour for the smooth line. Changing the second example to add an explicit call to aes(color...) for the geom_smooth() call results in the same result as the first example.

```
ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length), data = trainData) +
geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
geom_smooth(aes(color=Species))
```

Comment: Thanks! Understood now